# How to replace a subselect with a join in a case statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery

I have a SQL query with a case statement. The case statement has a subquery. I want to replace (delete) the subselect with a join. It is possible? How can i do it?

The Query:

```
SELECT tablex.Abnumber, CASE WHEN Abdate is not null AND isnull(Abnumber,0) > 1 AND Abdate < (SELECT Abdate FROM t_tablex WHERE Annumber = @Annumber AND Abnumber= @Abnumber-1) THEN 'bla bla' ELSE '' END
FROM t_tablex AS tablex
WHERE (@Annumber IS NULL OR tablex.Annumber= @Annumber)
  AND (@AbnumberIS NULL OR tablex.Abnumber= @Abnumber)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  More information is needed about the data.

Comment: Would be great if you could provide some data. I'm also intrested in what your tables looks like. More specifically tables names, column names and what primary and foreign key you've got. Another question that comes in mind is where your local variables are being set. Is this inside a stored procedure perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I tried some things and found the following solutions:

Solution 1 (replace subselect with inner join):

```
SELECT tablex.Abnumber, 
    CASE WHEN tablex.Abdate is not null 
        AND isnull(tablex.Abnumber,0) > 1 
        AND tablex.Abdate < tablex2.Abdate 
    THEN 'bla bla' 
    ELSE '' END 
FROM t_tablex AS tablex
INNER JOIN t_tablex as tablex2
    ON tablex.Annumber = tablex2.Annumber
    AND tablex.Abnumber = tablex2.Abnumber + 1 
WHERE tablex.Annumber = ISNULL( @Annumber, tablex.Annumber)
AND tablex.Abnumber = ISNULL( @Abnumber, tablex.Abnumber)
```

Solution 2 (with LAG()):

```
SELECT base.*
FROM ( 
    SELECT tablex.Abnumber, 
        CASE WHEN tablex.Abdate is not null 
            AND tablex.Abnumber > 1 
            AND tablex.Abdate < LAG( tablex.Abdate, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY tablex.Annumber ORDER BY tablex.Abnumber) 
        THEN 'bla bla' 
        ELSE '' END AS ERG
    FROM t_tablex AS tablex
    WHERE tablex.Annumber = ISNULL( @Annumber, tablex.Annumber )
    AND tablex.Abnumber BETWEEN ISNULL( @Abnumber , tablex.Abnumber) - 1 
    AND ISNULL( @Abnumber, tablex.Abnumber )
    ) base
WHERE
base.Abnumber = ISNULL( @Abnumber, base.Abnumber )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tablex.Abnumber, 
        CASE WHEN  isnull(Abnumber,0) > 1 AND Abdate < a.Abdate THEN 'bla bla' ELSE '' END  
FROM t_tablex AS tablex 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Abdate 
           FROM  t_tablex
           WHERE Annumber = @Annumber AND Abnumber= @Abnumber-1
) A ON A.Annumber = tablex.Annumber AND a.Abnumber = tablex.Abnumber
 WHERE tablex.Annumber= @Annumber 
AND  tablex.Abnumber= @Abnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `LAG()` does what you want:

```
SELECT x.Abnumber,
       (CASE WHEN x.Abdate is not null AND  
                  x.Abnumber > 1 AND
                  x.Abdate < prev_Abdate
             THEN 'bla bla'
             ELSE '' 
        END)
FROM (SELECT x.*, 
             LAG(Abdate) OVER (PARTITION BY Annumber ORDER BY Abnumber) as prev_Abdate)
      FROM t_tablex x
     ) x
WHERE (@Annumber IS NULL OR x.Annumber= @Annumber) AND
      (@Abnumber IS NULL OR x.Abnumber = @Abnumber);
```

This is not *exactly* equivalent to your query, unless some assumptions are made about the data.  However, I suspect it is actually what you intend.